# Is there any value to "boilerplate comments?"

Tags: java, hibernate, comments

In an application that makes use of Hibernate we have several entity classes which map to tables in the database schema. I have seen entities which a lot of seemingly useless JavaDoc comments and can't help but wonder if there's any usefulness there at all.

Is there any value to these brain-dead comments? And if not, can you make an argument for its removal?

```
/**
 * MyClass entity.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="my_class")
public class MyClass {

    // Fields

    /** The id. */
    private Integer id;

    /** The name. */
    private String name;

...

    // Constructors

    /**
     * default constructor.
     */
    public MyClass() {
    }

...

    // Property accessors
    /**
     * Gets the id.
     *
     * @return the id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the id.
     *
     * @param id
     *            the new id
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

...

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No value.

Arguments for removal:

1. Makes the code longer so more to scroll though. I'd rather see mode code on my screen at once than useless comments taking 50% of the screen.
2. Once you see that the comments are just fluff, you'll probably just get in the habit of skipping over comments. Even ones that aren't fluff. So they actually de-value any useful comments.

Comment: Your second point is excellent; I hadn't thought that useless comments would induce a (bad) learned behavior of ignoring all comments.

Answer (score 2):

While I do think some of that can be useless, I do tend to put similar type comments in my code. The purpose being that it becomes easy to determine the overall layout of the code and where things are without having to read and interpret the code itself. For example, In my classes, I tend to structure it like this:

```
class Foo{

    /************************
     * Variable Declaration
     */
    //Define some variables here

    /************************
     * Constructors
     */
    //Put some constructors here

    /************************
     * Methods
     */
    //Put some methods here

    /**
     * @return A description of what the variable is, not just that you are returning it
     *         so the user doesn't have to find the variable definition above and look for
     *         a description there.
     */
    void exMethod(){
        return var;
    }

}
```

In this way, if I have a really long class, and I'm simply scrolling through it, the markers for the different sections are easily visible and create a nice divide. But that's just my preference. Others may consider that overkill and not want to include them in the code.

Comment: This is a very good point, and I encourage it. This kind of comment serves an organizational purpose. My question is concerned more with the "String name; // The name." JavaDoc comments.

Comment: Yes that does tend to be a bit useless. If the purpose/use of the variable is obvious, I don't comment it with a description. And obviously if the description is nothing more than a repeat of the variable name, then I leave it out. I would only give a comment on a variable if it serves to add more information that the variable name itself doesn't already provide.

Comment: "if I have a really long class" Have you thought of having smaller classes? If a class of mine gets too long to understand without comments, I regard that as a code smell and refactor into smaller classes.

Comment: Sometimes you just need a long class though. A class should encompass everything necessary to contain the idea that the class represents. Sometimes that means a lot of different methods (particlularly for a class that is meant for calculations). It would be a mistake to break that into smaller classes if that meant breaking one single idea into lesser classes that are only part of the whole. Just like single a sentence should convey one, cohensive idea, so should a class convey one cohensive purpose. No more and no less.